# Mongo - Update elements in nested array

Tags: mongodb, updates

I've a document that looks like

```
{
  _id: "123xyz",
  profile: {
    emails: [
      {
        "address" : "foo@gmail.com",
        "primary" : true
      },
      {
        "address" : "bar@gmail.com",
        "primary" : false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When a user set an email address as primary, and if he already has other emails, I want to set those other emails as non primary ie I'd like to give all the emails different from the new primary one the flag `primary: false`. According to some other SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371801/meteor-mongo-nested-arrays-update), this should work:

```
db.users.update(
  { _id: userId, 'profile.emails.address': { $ne: newEmailAddress } },
  { $set: { 'profile.emails.$.primary': false } }
);
```

But it fails with `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: profile.emails.$.primary`

The original document currently has just one email that differs from `newEmailAddress`.

Comment: please elaborate it more what you want ?

Comment: Well I'd like the emails different to `newEmailAddress` to get the flag `primary: false` and the query to run without failing

Answer (score 3):

Here I found an answer to your question:
[Update an item in an array that is in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166615/update-an-item-in-an-array-that-is-in-an-array)

And with that solution in this case (with your structure):

```
db.mail.update({"profile.emails": {$elemMatch: {"address": 
{$ne: "new@gmail.com" }}}}, {$set: {"profile.emails.$.primary": "false"}})
```